# Doing a COUNT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have the following two tables -- userprofile and videoinfo. videoInfo has a FK to userprofile.

```
CREATE TABLE `userprofile_userprofile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   ...
 )

CREATE TABLE `userprofile_videoinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `uploaded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  KEY `userprofile_videoinfo_e43a31e7` (`uploaded_by_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `uploaded_by_id_refs_id_492ba9396be0968c` FOREIGN KEY (`uploaded_by_id`) REFERENCES `userprofile_userprofile` (`id`)
)
```

What is the SQL statement I would use to show the count of videos each userprofile has and order by COUNT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id as userId, count(v.uploaded_by_id) as videosCount
FROM userprofile_userprofile u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN userprofile_videoinfo v
        ON v.uploaded_by_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY count(v.uploaded_by_id) DESC
```

Comment: +1: The OUTER JOIN is best, if the OP needs to see counts for all users.  An inner JOIN would not show users whose counts are zero.

Comment: @Scorpi0: this actually gives a count of 1 to all userprofiles without a video upload. Why does it do that, and how can I fix this?

Comment: @David542 : updated, you have to count v.uploaded_by_id and not * !

Comment: @Scorpi0: change the `count(*)` in the ORDER BY too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uploaded_by_id, COUNT(ID) as cnt
FROM userprofile_videoinfo
GROUP BY uploaded_by_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```